# Buddypress event image not display in homepage

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I used buddypress event manager plugin.

To display the event i should use this short code`[activity-stream per_page=10 ]`.

Now 10 events are displayed correctly. But image will not displayed. If i create an new event means the Name of the event, Who's created , Time will be displayed.

But i want to display image also. Kindly help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you set all images correctly for each event? even as "feature image"?

Comment: Please provide some code you tried

Comment: Yes i used all images correctly

Comment: share also the link to this buddypress event manager plugin

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/

Comment: if you go into the single page of the single event, can you see the event image? please, share a screen shot of the event settings in the administration back end

Comment: did you set the `feature image` as [here at the bottom right corner?](http://d1mkunav5pg7l3.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/events-edit.png)